# Removing unneeded frameworks from the Cordova Diagnostics Plugin

Tags: cordova, permissions, cordova-plugins

We use the [Cordova Diagnostics plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) on our ionic/cordova app to check if the user has access to the camera since we have both a barcode scanner plugin and camera plugin in our app. We don't use the bluetooth, background location, motion, or contacts frameworks of the plugin but XCode still requires us to put explanations of what those unused services are used for and they are marked as required permissions for the app.

Is there anyway to disable the unused frameworks and just use the ones we want? I tried removing the `<framework src="CoreBluetooth.framework" />` and other related lines from the plugin.xml and the `"CoreBluetooth.framework": 1,` line from the `platforms/ios/frameworks.json` file but that didn't work. When I uploaded it to the app store, it still gave me the warning that I needed those descriptions. What else can I do? I don't want customers to think we gather all this info from their device that when we actually aren't.

Answer (score 0):

> XCode still requires us to put explanations of what those unused services are used for

Diagnostic plugin [inserts placeholders for all usage descriptions](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L26) so you should only need to override the ones that you actually use. These messages will only be displayed to the user if you actually request the related permission at runtime, e.g. [`cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestBluetoothAuthorization()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestbluetoothauthorization).

> they are marked as required permissions for the app

Where are they marked as required permissions?
As far as I'm aware these permissions are not displayed to the user e.g. on the App Store page or at install time, only when the app requests run-time permission to use them.